# Promise.await() vs. Top-Level Await?

Tags: node.js, meteor, async-await, promise

This does not work:

```
function myFunction(myObject){
    let IM = await connectors.myModel.update({
        myField: true,
    }, {
        where: {id: myObject.id},
        returning: true,
    });
}
```

But this does work:

```
function myFunction(myObject){
    let IM = Promise.await(connectors.myModel.update({
        myField: true,
    }, {
        where: {id: myObject.id},
        returning: true,
    }));
}
```

I understand that you can't use `await` outside of an `async function`. What's the difference between `Promise.await()` and the upcoming node.js feature, `Top-Level await`?

Comment: What is your `Promise`? There is no such thing as `Promise.await` in vanilla JS

Comment: Good question. I have no idea yet why this code works. `Promise` isn't a variable -- it's just the keyword `Promise`.

Comment: Oh okay -- it must be because my build tool is Meteor. I didn't know Meteor did something special with Promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fibers and Promise.await

Meteor uses `fibers` (coroutines, [repo here](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers)) under the hood to support asynchronous programming. This is why you can write in Meteor synchronous-style code on the server, allthough it may be async in nature:

```js
const doc = MyCollection.findOne()
doc.someProp // yeay it's there without await
```

Same goes with `Promise.await`, which uses the current fiber as execution environment. You can run the following code in a Meteor Method:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  test () {
    const someAsyncFn = async () => 'foo'
    const foo = Promise.await(someAsyncFn())
    return foo // 'foo'
  }
})
```

### Top-Level await and native async/await

Now you amy wonder why in 2022 Meteor still won't use real antive async/await. Simply it's a 10 year old framework with high stability and backwards compatibility. The step towards native async/await requires to drop fibers, which itself is deeply built into the core of Meteor!

However, the discussion to move to native async/await already led to development of it: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/discussions/11505

With upcoming Meteor 2.8 there will be the first native async/await support.
Top-Level async will be available after that and [is still  wip](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/12095).

### What should I do?

For now you should start slowly rewriting code to async/await with beginning of Meteor 2.8 and try to avoid `Promise.await` unless not possible otherwise.

You can already write server methods async-style without affecting behaviour that much:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  test: async function () {
    const someAsyncFn = async () => 'foo'
    const foo = await someAsyncFn()
    return foo // 'foo'
  }
})
```

For now you can't use top-level await and need to wrap it in an IIFE block:

```js
(async () => {

})()
  .then(res => {})
  .catch(e => {})
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's because Meteor, my build tool, is doing something cool with Promises.

Comment: And by "cool" you mean "non-standard"?

Comment: It seems like I've had something similar to top-level await and used it for years. It works great. I wish it were standard and I guess top-level await will be standard in upcoming versions of node.js.

Answer (score -2):

Promise.await takes an array of promises, and resolves when they all resolve, returning and array of results when it resolves.

Top level await lets you call await as if your entire global code was inside an async block.

Your code works because your are not awaiting Promise.await.  You should be, or calling `then`.

Put your code in an IIFE block if you want to await at the top level.

```
;(async function() {
  await foo();
})();
```